# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - ImportError: cannot import name 'decode' from 'cognitojwt'

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Flask application that opens locally (with Python 3.6 and also Python 3.8) but encounters issues in my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment - Python 3.8 running on 64-bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.2. It fails with the following errors:

```
2023/11/26 12:45:52 [error] 1360#1360: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ..., server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "..."
2023/11/26 12:45:52 [error] 1360#1360: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ..., server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "...", referrer: ".."
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'decode' from 'cognitojwt'
```

My env in Severe status..

```
requirements.txt:


Werkzeug==0.16.1
bcrypt
pandas
flask
flask_sqlalchemy
flask_restplus
flask_praetorian
psycopg2-binary
flask-cors
Flask-Cognito
```

The code written originally on January 2022 but also worked fine on July 2023